# Can't change from Python 2.7 on VS Code on Big Sur

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-code

I've installed Python 3.9 on my Mac, and used Python: Select Interpreter in VS Code to change to it. VS Code is telling me its using Python 3.9 in the status bar, but when I type "python -V" in the terminal it tells me its using Python 2.7. See attached screenshot.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTyPX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.7 comes pre-installed in MacOS. The command `python` refers to it.

If you want to use python 3.x instead, you have to use `python3` (as in `python3 --version`)

If you would like to invoke python3 even when you type `python`, you can add an alias to your `bashrc` or your `zshrc` (depending on which you use) such as

```
alias python="python3"
```